# Formula for the area of the interior of a closed contour in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration, area, curves

Let $\gamma \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$ be closed contour in the complex plane. What is the formula for the area of the interior $I(\gamma)$ of $\gamma$? My assumption is that it involves some kind of contour integral. If possible, please kindly show me a derivation and direct me to a resource where I can research this further. Many thanks.

Comment: Interior of a closed contour is  a very difficult concept. To make your intuitive idea of points inside the contour precise you have get into some deep topology. So there is no hope of finding  a formula for the areas enclosed by the contour in general. You will need what are called Jordan curves even to define points 'inside'  the contour.

Comment: @Zak1120: If you are also  mechanically inclined: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planimeter

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: sir, can one use a mechanical planimeter to find enclosed areas for curved topographies in 3D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not differ from the case of a parametric curve $x=f(t),y=g(t)$, such that the area can be computed as

$$A=\oint x\,dy=-\oint y\,dx=\frac12\oint(x\,dy-y\,dx).$$

Noticing that $x\,dx+y\,dy$ is a total differential, which integrates to $0$, this explains the formula

$$\frac12\oint \bar z\,dz=iA.$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that applying Green formula for $\bar z dz$ we get that the area inside $\gamma$ (assuming the curve is simple and piecewise smooth say) is $\frac{1}{2i}\int_{\gamma}{\bar z }dz$